# How do I add a Facebook like page box to a Squarespace website?

Tags: html, facebook, widget, xfbml, squarespace

I'm trying to add a facebook like page box to my Squarespace website and having some troubles.

The code for the box is generated from facebook, it works fine when in development mode, it shows the like box functioning as it should. But then when I log out and am just viewing the website an error comes up telling me "*The page you are trying to access is restricted or unavailable*".

The code I entered from FB was:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FNexus-Magazine%2F116070391739244&amp;width=250&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=427" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:427px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I contacted Squarespace support and they replied:
lease note, Writing, adding, and amending coding within your squarespace site is an advanced modification. Squarespace does not offer code troubleshooting/support. You will need to check the validity of the coding you are using against the source to make sure the code is correct.

That being said, In the process of locating the issue, I managed to fix the coding for your facebook 'button'. The address to the page you were trying to reference wasn't displaying pertinent characters, Like the ":" And "//" in "http://" All of the characters were displaying as HTML coding for special characters: "%2" = "/"

Once I changed the HTML representations of these characters within your coding for the Facebook page, the issue resolved.

They changed the original code to:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http://www.facebook.com/Fpages/FNexus-Magazine/F116070391739244&amp;width=270&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=427" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:427px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Although the issue was NOT resolved.

Have you any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,

Scott

Comment: This did the trick http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=284739 ... :| This new user stuff is BS I can't answer my own questions within 24 hours or post photos to further outline what I'm being a retard about as I first need to get 10 of these site brownie points.

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=284739 worked.